# SQL query (in ZOHO reports) to join two tables by subtotas :-O

Tags: sql

if you are out there, please help me:

I **have** 2 different tables, with different columns and no primary key:

1 - daily actual sales data
  2 - monthly budget sales data

I **need**:

```
- one consolidated table with monthly actual sales (counted) and montly budget sales, to compare monthly sales vs budget.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: if you can give table structure here, sample records and expected output,the answer should be possible.

Comment: Can you provide a DB schema of the two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Of course.

You can aggregate the numbers for every month from the actual sales data table using sum() and group by and can join into this the budget table via the month column.